# Can a third party spoof packets to interfere with already opened connections?

Tags: networking, handshake, spoofing

Here is the scenario I have in mind.

Computer A is a server that clients connect to, but the clients must pass a ban check.
Computer B is a server that acts as a ban aggregator. Bans from multiple servers come here, and can be access by any server via an API.
Computer C is a banned client that wants to bypass a ban and connect to Computer A.

This is the login process:
Computer C sends Computer A its username and password combo.
Computer A receives login info and makes sure it's valid.
Computer A asks Computer B for Computer C's username's bans.
Computer B sends Computer A the ban records.
Computer A receives the ban records and checks to see if Computer A should be disconnected due to a ban and acts accordingly.

So, my question is if Computer C can spoof Computer B's response to Computer A's query about his ban record. Unfortunately, I don't know much about sockets and how TCP handshakes work.

If computer C knew what a response from Computer B that said he had no bans looked like, knew when he needed to send the fake response to Computer A, and spoofed his IP to resemble that of Computer B's, could he successfully trick Computer A into thinking that he had no bans on record?

Answer (score 2):

You could pretty quickly avoid this issue if you simply signed the responses from B with a private key known only to you. Then, A would validate the response from B and reject them if the signature didn't match. You can include the public key part of the signing key with the public API.

Comment: So, it is possible if the responses don't have a key you can validate and that a third party doesn't know?